# Image movement in With Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have 1 *view controller* in my `main.storyboard` and I have a `UIImageView` in there which is linked up to *swipe gesture recognizer*.

My goal is to have the user *swipe left* and the image continuously moves left, then if the user swipes right/up/down it will stop moving left and move in the new direction.

I have so far tried using this approach which doesn't quite do it:

```
-(void)screenWasSwipedDown
{
    BackMovement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0035 target:self selector:@selector(BackMovingDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];       
}

-(void)BackMovingDown
{    
    Back.center = CGPointMake(Back.center.x, Back.center.y+1);
}
```

I have done this for each direction, it does work but when the user swipes a new direction it does not stop moving (down in this case) and just piles the timers on top of each other. So two left swipes make it go faster, or left and up make it go diagonal.

If anyone knows how to do this please help me out

Comment: You need to stop the `NSTimer` (see `invalidate` etc.) Please, name your methods and var starting with a lowercase.

Comment: @Larme thanks I will try, what's the best way of stopping the NSTimer? I'm guessing if statements but what form would this take?

Answer (score 0):

You can invalidate your timer with `[backMovement invalidate];` Make your timer a weak instance variable, and it will become nil as soon as you invalidate it.

That way you can have your swipe code invalidate the timer and create a new one.
 You shouldn't need to create separate timers for each direction, since only one will be running at a time. Just create a single movementTimer

```
-(void)screenWasSwipedDown
{
  [movementTimer invalidate]; //Also causes the timer to become nil
  movementTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0035 
    target:self 
    selector:@selector(BackMovingDown) 
    userInfo:nil 
    repeats:YES];       
}
```

Note that animating with a timer is not the best way to go. It would be better to use UIView animation, and use the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option so a new animation continues from the location of the last one.